# lxml relative xPath doesn't return result relative to the given HtmlElement

Tags: html, python-3.x, dom, xpath, lxml

I apply a relative XPath (`./`) to an HtmlElement and it doesn't return any results. When I try using double dots (`../`), it returns all results matching from root HTML instead of descendant results of that specific HtmlElement. I am not sure what is wrong here.

The version of lxml is 4.5.2

Example:

```
<html>
  <h3>
  <p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Sample</td>
        <td>Sample</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </p>
  <h3>
  <p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Sample 2</td>
        <td>Sample 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </p>
</html>
```

Code

```
r = requests.get('http://website.com')
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
tables = tree.xpath("(//p/table)")

for table in tables:
    result = table.xpath('.//td')
    text = result.text_content()
```

The first iteration in the loop should return "Sample" texts and the second iteration should return "Sample 2" texts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the HTML itself. When I inspect the document on a browser, it shows that `<p>` is the parent of the `<table>` elements however requested HTML revealed that `<p></p>` is actually the sibling element preceding `<table>`.